# fragment caching for jinja2 templates

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I‘m trying to improve the rendering performance of my jinja2 templates in the context of Django (changing from the django engine to the jinja2 already gave a significant increase of around 5 times quicker rendering time).

For context, I have a quite large template where major sections stay always the same making them suitable to the idea of caching. Then the other remaining sections within the template will almost always be different to the previous call making them less suitable for caching.

I had the idea of splitting my template so that there is a base template (with the non changing sections) and the child template which extends the base template with the dynamic sections. The idea behind this was that the base template is cached, however I could not find any documentation which would validate this idea.

The other approach I came across is template fragment caching (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) which looked promising, but I was not able to get my head around on how to achieve this result using the jinja2 engine.

I would like to do performance tests for both approaches, so was therefore looking for guidance on how to achieve fragment caching with jinja2 and validation if the base template is cached separately.

Is the base template cached separately when using the extend mechanism in jinja2 templates?

edit: changed to more explicit question following comment

Comment: Please ask a specific technical question! Questions for guidance or the amount of experience people have can not be accepted.

Comment: you should read jinja2 documentation to see if it has similar function.